# Using listing for displaying Matlab code

Tags: listings, matlab, kerning

I'm trying to display matlab code in a LaTeX document and the comments are typeset with an ugly space between letters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\lstset{tabsize=2}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function gramschmidt(A) %The columns of A are the initial basis to the subspace
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

results in [image]

Is there a way to improve the kerning (or whatever its called) of the text in the comments?

Comment: You may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks better with

```
\lstset{flexiblecolumns=true}
```

[image]